# DocuSign - Adopt Signature Settings (Disable style selection)

Tags: docusignapi

In my account, the adopt signature settings (Disable Style Selection) is unchecked by default and it is non-editable.
Is there any reason for this and where can i go to get this configuration checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend reaching out to DocuSign Support and asking them to enable "Disable Style Signature" for you.

It is a backend setting that is not enabled by default.

Comment: Got it enabled by the DocuSign Support. Thanks!